# Can you manually refresh a binding if you only have a reference to the Binding object, not what it's bound to?

Tags: wpf, binding, multibinding

In our code, we have an instance of a `Binding` object which we need to manually refresh.  The problem is we don't know where it's actually applied.

Normally, if you have the target object and property the binding is set on, you can get the `BindingExpression`, then call `UpdateTarget()`. However in our particular case, we're doing this in a `ProvideValue` method of a `MarkupExtension` which is ultimately used on a `Setter` in a `Style` and the binding technically isn't bound until the style is applied, which is loooong after the ProvideValue has been called.

Now we've gotten around this limitation by, from inside `ProvideValue`, wrapping that `Binding` in a `MultiBinding` and setting up a second `Binding` to a source and property which we control. Then by touching that property, we force the MultiBinding to refresh, which forces the bindings to all be re-evaluated.  But it's just such a hack! It works, but it's still a hack!

So is this possible?  My guess is no as my understanding is a binding merely sets up a `BindingExpression` that handles the actual work, but I could be wrong.

So can this be done?

Comment: Unclear what you are asking, but calling the OnPropertyChanged(nameof(PropertyName)); would tell the UI to reevaluate the Property.

Comment: That's only true for classes that properly implement `INotifyPropertyChanged` (technically you can implement it without adding that method, but it's not advisable), but a `DependencyObject` doesn't implement that interface anyway.